# From a list of lists, how can I find list which have specific word in it

Tags: list, token, review

So I have reviews about amusement parks, and I want to pull specific sentences which have food review in them.

So I tokenized by sentences so now I have list of lists. Lists being each review and containing list of each sentence separated full stops.

How can I only pull sentences which have word "food" in them.

Kindly help

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include a sample data for your post and your desired output. Also, please share some codes you have tried to get your desired output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
sentences_with_food = []
for review in list:
    for sentence in review:
        if 'food' in sentence.lower().split():
            sentences_with_food.append(sentence)
# sentences_with_food now contains all the sentences which contain "food" word
```

(note that `lower()` is needed for occurrences of "Food", "FOOD", "fOoD", etc.; and `split()` is needed otherwise also sentences with words like "brainfood" ed similia since it contains "food")